# Permission denied to mkdir in /mnt

Tags: nfs, root

i am trying to mkdir inside /mnt/logs/ in order to mount an NFS mountpoint. But i am getting:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/mnt/logs/server2': Permission denied
```

/mnt/logs/ is full of other NFS mountpoints.

```
root@server1 ~]# ll -d /mnt/logs/
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 0 Nov  3  2016 /mnt/logs/

root@server1 ~]# getfacl /mnt/logs/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: mnt/logs/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong or missing here?
Thanks

Comment: is this a local or mounted file system?
could you add the output of df -h /mnt/logs

Comment: mounted in read only?pls show output of `mount`

Comment: Is `/mnt/logs` itself an NFS mount point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you very much for your posts. I found what i was missing here, yes its an NFS moint point and is managed by autofs /etc/auto.logs.

from /etc/auto.master
+auto.master
/mnt/logs        /etc/auto.logs           --ghost

Comment: " I found what i was missing here, " can you detial your own answer and mark it as accepted please?